# "Registering two gradient with name 'BlockLSTM'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I get an error when i am trying to process an image.
What should I do with the error like this?
exactly this:

> Registering two gradient with name 'BlockLSTM'! (Previous registration
>   was in register
>   C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\registry.py:66)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me just a few minutes ago. The answer to fixing this error is to install the latest version of tensorflow by typing this:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: Is this issue related to the TF version?

Comment: @xtluo Yeah, it plays a role in this.